# Yahoo Finance API Special Keys

Tags: ruby, api, url, yahoo, yahoo-finance

I'm working on fleshing out an open source ruby gem that queries Yahoo Finance's api, using `http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=SOME_COMPANY&f=SOME_SPECIAL_TAGS` This returns a csv, or it can do JSON but either works.

This works great; however, I don't have a complete list of the special tags that I use to query their API.  The tags are simple single letter or a single letter followed by a single number to query for specific information, such as r = p/e ratio or a2 = average daily volume.

As much as I've searched I've only ever seen around 85 or so of these special tags, but based on their system they should be able to take as many as 260 special keys.  I'm interested in finding all such keys since I would like to be able to find such things as beta or cash flow of a company.  If anyone can point me to a complete list it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search engine found [this](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/enumQuoteProperty).

First 10 rows . . .

```
AfterHoursChangeRealtime  After Hours Change (Realtime)  c8
AnnualizedGain            Annualized Gain                g3
Ask                       Ask                            a0
AskRealtime               Ask (Realtime)                 b2
AskSize                   Ask Size                       a5
AverageDailyVolume        Average Daily Volume           a2
Bid                       Bid                            b0
BidRealtime               Bid (Realtime)                 b3
BidSize                   Bid Size                       b6
BookValuePerShare         Book Value Per Share           b4
```

If Yahoo! doesn't document their API, you'll probably have to discover the tags by reading a lot of newsgroup posts or by reading a lot of source code. The YDN forums seem suspiciously silent when it comes to question about the finance API, and they don't show a finance API in their [YDN index](http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html?category=api).

Comment: I was hoping not to have to go through all the possibilities myself. And I know, they seem to passively discourage its use.  If only google still had their finance API.  Perhaps there's a wall street conspiracy theory in there. Is there a stack for those?